# How to scroll UITextView in a UITableViewCell to the top of keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios7

I need to create a `UITableView` in which a `UITableViewCell` contains a `UITextView` very much like the Notes field in Contacts app.

When the text view is touched, the keyboard is brought up and the cursor is properly scrolled to the top of the keyboard.  How do I do that?

[image]

When more lines are entered, the `UITextView` is properly expanded and the `UITableView` is scrolled.  How is this done?

[image]

I've been experimenting many examples and solutions from Stack Overflow.  Most are dealing with resizing the height of the text view.  I was able to get that working.  However, I haven't been able to find anything that deals table view cell and text view in edit mode.  I hope some experienced iOS developer would able to give a hand here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you need here is the delegate methods of Keyboard. It provides functions to adjust the layout when a keyboard is brought up.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by offsetting UITableView content as the keyboard appears.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow
{    
     CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);

     self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
     self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

}

And resetting the edgeinset as the keyboard returns:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

For the code and implementation I recommend [HERE](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/keyboard-content-offset/)

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of position the keyboard.  It's more about how to resize UITextView and UITableViewCell when the text changes.